# How to get URL of a document if I have the documents item ID (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, 2013, custom-actions

I am trying to create a Ribbon Custom Action in SharePoint 2013 that will e-mail links of selected documents in a document library. I can get the Item ID's of selected items, but how can I use these to create a URL to insert into the e-mail body?

My javascript so far:

```
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();

window.location.href="mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body="+items[0].ID+"message%20goes%20here";
```

**Edit: Found a solution below**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my question. I had to use JavaScript to look in the elements on the page for the href value for each list item.

```
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
var url = "";
var length = items.length;
for (var i=0; i<length; i++)
{
url = url + "%0D%0A" + document.getElementById(items[i].id).getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
}
window.location.href="mailto:?subject=Subject&body="+url;
```

I blogged about it here: http://leochensharepoint.blogspot.com/2013/04/using-javascript-with-custom-actions-in.html